# I cannot navigate back to question from Image page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

When there is an attached image in a question on any SE site, clicking on it opens it in a full screen mode. There is no way to redirect back to the question unless you press browser's back button. Keyboard's escape key does not work, neither there is explicit close button. Is there any different key combination to escape out from that page, or shall I be using back button of the browser?

Attached screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

**From the comment:**
"Because it's a link to another site. It's not being opened in a lightbox or anything. Notice that the address bar says imgur.com" - So is it possible to prevent this redirection and open image as popup or something, or using back button is fine?

Comment: Because it's a link to another site. It's not being opened in a lightbox or anything. Notice that the address bar says imgur.com.

Comment: Oh okay..Oops I didnot notice that..so back button is only option then..